# Image of a convex set under a compact map

Tags: functional-analysis

How do I prove that $T(\overline\Omega)\subset\overline\Omega$, where
$$T:\overline\Omega\rightarrow X$$ is compact (X Banach, $\Omega\subset X$ convex and bounded) and $$T(\partial\Omega)\subset\Omega$$

Is this even true for any convex subset of X?

Comment: Let $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, with $Tx=2x$ and $\Omega = (-1,1)$, then $T(\overline{\Omega})=[-2,2]\not \subset [-1,1]$?

Comment: Your example doens't satisfy the second condition of T :($T(\partial(-1,1))\subset(-1,1)$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was another claim (yeah, doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 0):

First $\overline{\Omega}$ is a convex set, and you can show pretty easily that $T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big)$ is convex. Furthermore $\overline{\Omega}$  is bounded and therefore by compactness of $T$ we know therefore that $T \big( \overline{\Omega} \big)$ is compact (can be seen by sequential compactness). By the Krein-Milman theorem we know that:

$ \overline{conv} \Big( Ext \big( T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big) \big) \Big)= T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big)  $

Then it just remains to show that $Ext \big( T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big) \big)\subseteq \overline{\Omega}$. But since for a given set $A$, we know that $Ext(A)\cap int(A)=\emptyset$, and $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus int(A)$ we know then that $Ext(A)\subseteq \partial A$. Applied to the problem hand it specifically gives us that:

$ Ext\Big( T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big) \Big) \subseteq T\big( \partial \Omega \big) $

And finally by the assumption $T\Big( \partial \Omega \Big) \subseteq \Omega$, and therefore $Ext \big( T\big( \overline{\Omega} \big) \big)\subseteq \Omega$ as needed.

Comment: $Ext(T(\overline\Omega))\subset T(\partial\Omega)?$ Isn't it $Ext(T(\overline\Omega))\subset \partial T(\Omega)?$

Comment: I also want to say that $Ext\big( T( \overline{\Omega}) \big)= T \big( Ext(\overline{\Omega} ) \big)$, which shows the inclusion I wrote.

Comment: Do you have a proof for this statement? Or a link to a proof?

Comment: But $Ext(T(\overline{\Omega}))$ is not $T(Ext(\overline{\Omega}))$ in general. Take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $\overline{\Omega}=D^2$ the unit disc and $T(x,y)=(x/2,0)$. In this case, we have $Ext(T(\overline{\Omega}))=\{(-1/2,0),(1/2,0)\}$ and $T(Ext(\overline{\Omega}))=[-1/2,1/2]\times{0}$.